# Gsoap databinding how to remove namespace definitions in my xml

Tags: data-binding, namespaces, gsoap

So im very new to gsoap and im fumbling around trying to my resulting xml code to match the xml that I need.  For some reason all of my xml looks like this:

```
<ns1:system>linux</ns1:system>
```

but the problem is I need it to look like this:

```
<system>linux</system>
```

Is there some sort of option/flag that I can turn on / off to remove the ns1 or do I have to do something completely different?  Like I said I am very new to gsoap, so this could be something really simple that im missing or it could not even be a namespace problem, I have no idea.  If you need any more information I'll be happy to provide it.

Thanks for any help,
Josh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to turn off default element qualification. It's been too long for me to remember the gsoap recipe, but if you search for those terms you'll find it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I needed to change
//gsoap ns1   schema elementForm: unqualified
//gsoap ns1   schema attributeForm: unqualified

from qualified to unqualified